# Automate Android with script/code

Tags: automation, scripts

I was wondering if there was a way to automate/trigger different settings the way apps like Tasker and IFTTT do directly by coding. I had in mind somethin like a script that would run on the background checking every x time if the conditions are true and if they happen to be, trigger the actions it's meant to do. Basically,automate myphone via scrpits/codes i could write.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"directly by coding"_ - Isn't this what IFTTT does now?  It's an app that runs on your device with code that accesses/modifies/outputs the desired result.  There's nothing stopping you from downloading Android Studio and creating an app of your own that does exactly this.  :)

Comment: I get what you mean (and it's  something i have tought about) but isn't it going too far for just a script that checks sth and toggles sth? I mean, it's just and if/else... Anyways, thanks for your answer!

Comment: _"just a script that checks sth and toggles sth"_  -  You have to think about what _runs_ the script.  Scripts don't magically run themselves, their instructions are interpreted and processed by a controller.  You can either find an existing app that runs arbitrary scripts or write your own app.  To me, writing your own app is easier and safer.

Comment: Well then, i will take your advice. One minor detail: could you link a reference site from where i could find how to trigger this tasks, for example, en/disable mobile network or wifi. Ty!